# Input type file styling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I changed the input file button style with jquery, but i need space between the text input and the button.

How can i do it?

I use this tutorial : http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle.

Comment: file inputs are nearly impossible to style. most people hide them and impose other things on top of them and put the styling on that.

Comment: edit filestyle javascript, and edit .css function, or add some class to button element and style it with stylesheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit javascript source code, add some margin-left like me ("margin-left:"8px"),

try with this:

```
/*
 * Style File - jQuery plugin for styling file input elements
 *  
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2008 Mika Tuupola
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Based on work by Shaun Inman
 *   http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom
 *
 * Revision: $Id: jquery.filestyle.js 303 2008-01-30 13:53:24Z tuupola $
 *
 */

(function($) {

    $.fn.filestyle = function(options) {

        /* TODO: This should not override CSS. */
        var settings = {
            width : 250
        };

        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        };

        return this.each(function() {

            var self = this;
            var wrapper = $("<div>")
                            .css({
                                "width": settings.imagewidth + "px",
                                "height": settings.imageheight + "px",
                                "background": "url(" + settings.image + ") 0 0 no-repeat",
                                "background-position": "right",
                                "display": "inline",
                                "position": "absolute",
                                "overflow": "hidden"
                                "margin-left:"8px",
                            });

            var filename = $('<input class="file">')
                             .addClass($(self).attr("class"))
                             .css({
                                 "display": "inline",
                                 "width": settings.width + "px"
                             });

            $(self).before(filename);
            $(self).wrap(wrapper);

            $(self).css({
                        "position": "relative",
                        "height": settings.imageheight + "px",
                        "width": settings.width + "px",
                        "display": "inline",
                        "cursor": "pointer",
                        "opacity": "0.0"
                    });

            if ($.browser.mozilla) {
                if (/Win/.test(navigator.platform)) {
                    $(self).css("margin-left", "-142px");                    
                } else {
                    $(self).css("margin-left", "-168px");                    
                };
            } else {
                $(self).css("margin-left", settings.imagewidth - settings.width + "px");                
            };

            $(self).bind("change", function() {
                filename.val($(self).val());
            });

        });


    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i didn't get any think of your code, can you give me a link or something to explain it to me, i'm a beginner and i don't get every think